# I am trying to put a related table's data into a list serializer in Django Rest Framework

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, orm

I have two models:

```
class Settings(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    simplified = models.BooleanField()
    audio_download = models.BooleanField()
    show_read = models.BooleanField()
    show_pinyin = models.BooleanField()
    char_size = models.IntegerField()
    pinyin_size = models.IntegerField()
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'settings'


class HSK(models.Model):
    settings = models.OneToOneField(
        Settings, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hsk1 = models.BooleanField()
    hsk2 = models.BooleanField()
    hsk3 = models.BooleanField()
    hsk4 = models.BooleanField()
    hsk5 = models.BooleanField()
    hsk6 = models.BooleanField()
    hskplus = models.BooleanField()
```

I want my JSON returned by my GET request to look this like:

```
{
simplified: true,
audio_download: true,
...,
hsks: {
hsk1: true,
hsk2: true,
hsk3: false
 }
}
```

My GET request looks like this:

```
def get(self, request, user_id):
    settings_saves = Settings.objects.select_related(
        "hsk").filter(user_id=user_id)
    serializer = SettingsSerializer(settings_saves, many=False)
    return Response({"settings": serializer.data})
```

And my serializer looks like this:

```
class SettingsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    simplified = serializers.BooleanField()
    audio_download = serializers.BooleanField()
    show_read = serializers.BooleanField()
    show_pinyin = serializers.BooleanField()
    char_size = serializers.IntegerField()
    pinyin_size = serializers.IntegerField()
    start_date = serializers.DateField()
    end_date = serializers.DateField()
    hsk1 = serializers.BooleanField(source="hsk.hsk1")
    hsk2 = serializers.BooleanField(source="hsk.hsk2")
    hsk3 = serializers.BooleanField(source="hsk.hsk3")
    hsk4 = serializers.BooleanField(source="hsk.hsk4")
    hsk5 = serializers.BooleanField(source="hsk.hsk5")
    hsk6 = serializers.BooleanField(source="hsk.hsk6")
    hskplus = serializers.BooleanField(source="hsk.hskplus")
    hsks = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.BooleanField(), source="hsk")
```

I can get all of the fields individually:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "simplified": true,
        "audio_download": true,
        "show_read": true,
        "show_pinyin": true,
        "char_size": 1,
        "pinyin_size": 1,
        "start_date": "2020-05-06",
        "end_date": "2020-05-13",
        "hsk1": true,
        "hsk2": false,
        "hsk3": true,
        "hsk4": false,
        "hsk5": true,
        "hsk6": false,
        "hskplus": false
    }
}
```

But that's not what I want, I want all of the hsk values inside a list/array.

I've looked into ListField as you can see above, but I don't know how to implement it correctly, or if it is the correct solution for my problem.

How do I represent a list of data from a related table in a Django serializer?

Answer (score 0):

You just use the serializer nested inside the parent serializer, like so:

```
class SettingsHSKSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    settings_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    hsk1 = serializers.BooleanField()
    hsk2 = serializers.BooleanField()
    hsk3 = serializers.BooleanField()
    hsk4 = serializers.BooleanField()
    hsk5 = serializers.BooleanField()
    hsk6 = serializers.BooleanField()
    hskplus = serializers.BooleanField()


class SettingsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    simplified = serializers.BooleanField()
    audio_download = serializers.BooleanField()
    show_read = serializers.BooleanField()
    show_pinyin = serializers.BooleanField()
    char_size = serializers.IntegerField()
    pinyin_size = serializers.IntegerField()
    start_date = serializers.DateField()
    end_date = serializers.DateField()
    hsk = SettingsHSKSerializer()
```